# Please tell us the minimum API for using VrVideoView

Tags: api, android-4.4-kitkat, google-vr, android-8.1-oreo

I tried to run an application made with VrVideoView on two smartphones (galaxy grand max (android4.4.4) & galaxy j5 2017 (android 8.1)).
My app worked fine in android 8.1, but it did not work well in android 4.4.
Although the video was played in android 4.4, It did not respond to my smartphone movement and showed front view.
So I want to know the minimum specifications for VrVideoView to work properly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimum Android API level for running `Google-VR-SDK` is 19 but your problem is something else! It seems your device (galaxy grand max) has no Gyroscope! So you should establish another way to control angle view of playing video.

Try using this snippet in your `OnCreate` method to enable pure touch tracking:

```
if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_GYROSCOPE)) {
    videoWidgetView.setPureTouchTracking(true);
}
```

Hope it works :)